# flex slider 2 show control tabs

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am working with woothemes [flex slider](http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/) and it is great so far. I am using it right out of the box but I am very confuse on how to customize it. Everything works fine except I would like for the control navs(Left arrow, Right arrow) to always show on the slider and not just when I hover over the image. How can I make the slider arrows always show?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Edit these line in the CSS:

```
.flexslider:hover .flex-prev {
    opacity: 0.8;
    left: 5px;
}
```

To:

```
.flexslider .flex-prev {
    opacity: 0.8;
    left: 5px;
}
```

It will always show the control arrows.